# Custom shortcut for an item in the Preview app does not work unless the menu bar item containing that item is clicked once

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, preview

I have defined an app shortcut for Preview that triggers `Export…` on <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>. This keyboard shortcut does not trigger `Export…` unless I click on `File` once after I open Preview. It starts working fine from that point on. Before that, I hear a `Boop` sound when pressing the shortcut keys.

I also tried <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>, and it suffers from the same issue.

None of the two shortcuts are assigned to other operations in Preview, so I suspect the issue is not due to a conflict.

Defining the shortcut only for Preview or for All Applications does not make a difference.

Has anyone faced this problem before and knows how to solve it?

Running macOS Ventura (13.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who have [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/) installed, you can use "Trigger Menu Bar Menu-Item" and set the command path to `File;Export…`.

This no longer requires defining a custom shortcut and works better than trying to choose `Export…` with AppleScript because [AppleScript does not work well with Preview](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/458114/how-to-click-menu-bar-items-of-preview-with-applescript).